# Is writing "wishing you the best of health" at end of a letter considered a sentence fragment?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-fragments

Is writing "wishing you the best of health" at end of a letter considered a sentence fragment?

Comment: Who is doing the considering, and for what purpose? Almost any question of the form "Is X considered Y?" is unanswerable without that additional information.

Comment: I've seen closing emoticons. Sentence fragments are far less non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

That part of the letter is called the 'closing'. A more formal term is 'valediction'. It is perfectly fine as a fragment, or even a single word (i.e., 'Sincerely,').

The beginning/greeting of the letter is called the 'opening' or 'salutation'. This is also fine as a single word or fragment.

This picture shows the sections of the standard letter format:

[image]

Comment: In other words, "yes, but that doesn't make it incorrect."

Comment: I didn't want to confuse with a negative positive. ;)

Comment: Source for the image: https://g19ise1mackay.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/

Comment: Yes, good answer, but an informal letter would leave out Your Address and Your Reader's Address.  (Thank Goddess for e-mail.)

Answer (score 3):

Formerly the close to a formal letter would be something like

> > Wishing you the best of health, I remain,
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> John Smith

(with a handwritten signature above the name), which is both complimentary and grammatical.

It is no longer considered necessary to go to such lengths, but some pieces, such as 'Yours' or 'wishing you all the best' are often inserted in an attempt to dignify the message. They are certainly fragments if not fossils of a bygone age, but will be understood to be purely formalities. Whether they are helpful in any particular case is of course a stylistic judgement.